# F#: What is the difference between module let and type static let?

Tags: f#, static, module, singleton, types

Given the following:

```
module MyModule =
    let myObj = new MyObj()

type MyType() =
    static let myObj_ = new MyObj()
    static member myObj = myObj_
```

... are MyModule.myObj and MyType.myObj functionally (no pun intended) equivalent?

Whenever I call MyModule.myObj or MyType.myObj, I don't want the code to actually create a new object.  I just want access to methods on a singleton object.  I'm hoping that either of the above are suitable to that purpose.

Comment: Can you `open` your `MyType`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it and see?  I think these are the same, but I think you can author a MyObj type with a constructor that prints something and then easily verify the behavior with a short test program.  (Or maybe you're asking about something else I'm unclear about.)

Comment: Good idea, Brian.  I tried it, inserted a call to System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(string) in the () constructor.  The message box did not appear when I assigned MyModule.myObj or MyType.myObj to a value; it came up only when the singletons were initialized, so it does indeed look like both methods are equivalent.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, the object is definitely only created once.

There is a small (theoretical) difference though. With the static let, the object is only guaranteed to be created before MyType is used the first time ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483470.aspx)).

A module-level let binding is probably executed at program startup (or maybe when a module is first used?).